# Import JSON API into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I need to import some information from a JSON API URL into Google Sheets.

This is one example:
https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/game-api/race/details/69357391

I've been successful in importing basic information using IMPORTJSON available on Github:
https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/

But now I am faced with a type of information (is it an object? an array?) which seems to be different from the usual and I find myself unable to import this.

Here is a piece of it:

```
{
        "id": 969228010,
        "raceId": 69357391,
        "pegaId": 20042,
        "gate": 8,
        "pegaAttributes": "{\"id\":20042,\"name\":\"Bajaj\",\"ownerId\":623299,\"raceClass\":1,\"races\":1369,\"win\":504,\"lose\":865,\"energy\":18,\"gender\":\"Male\",\"bloodLine\":\"Campona\",\"breedType\":\"Legendary\",\"speed\":4.95,\"strength\":0.33,\"wind\":3.36,\"water\":1.84,\"fire\":8.83,\"lighting\":6.93,\"position\":4000,\"finished\":true,\"raceTime\":35.855,\"result\":8,\"gate\":8,\"lastSpeed\":22.721521955555556,\"stage\":4,\"isTopSpeedReached\":false,\"bonusStage\":false,\"topSpeed\":22.721521955555556,\"s0\":0,\"j0\":-0.02,\"a0\":0.4982185622222222,\"v0\":20.127527583333332,\"t0\":179.60000000000002,\"gears\":{},\"pb\":0}"**,
        "position": 11,
        "raceTime": 35.855,
        "reward": 0
      },
```

So using IMPORTJSON if I wanted to simply import the "raceId" element I'd go about doing this:

```
=ImportJSON("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/game-api/race/details/69357391", "/race/registers/raceId", "noHeaders")
```

But when trying to import any information from within `pegaAttributes`the IMPORTJSON is unable to recognize it as separate. The best I can do is import the whole block like so:

```
=ImportJSON("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/game-api/race/details/69357391", "/race/registers/pegaAttributes", "noHeaders")
```

So some of the information after `"pegaAttributes"` and inside brackets `{ }` I need to import. For example the attributes `raceTime` , `topSpeed`, `lastSpeed` and so on, how can I import this into Google Sheets?

Could anyone provide any pointers on how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your expected result as an image?

Comment: what you are looking for in a json inside another json, so you have to parse each pegaAttributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (you will have to apply JSON.parse on the pegaAttributes element which is also a json)

```
=importDataJSON(url,"id|position|raceTime","name|raceTime|topSpeed|lastSpeed")
```

with

```
function importDataJSON(url, items1, items2) {
  let result = []
  result = [[items1.split('|'), items2.split('|')].flat()]
  const obj = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  obj.race.registers.forEach(o => {
    let prov = []
    items1.split('|').forEach(item1 => prov.push(o[item1]))
    var pegaAttributes = JSON.parse(o.pegaAttributes)
    items2.split('|').forEach(item2 => prov.push(pegaAttributes[item2]))
    result.push(prov)
  })
  return result
}
```

with as parameters:

- url
- items1 (level 1) separated by |
- items2 (level2, under pegaAttributes) separated by |

[image]

### new edit

```
=importDataJSON(url,"totalReward|length","id|position|raceTime","name|raceTime|topSpeed|lastSpeed")
```

with

```
function importDataJSON(url, items0, items1, items2) {
  let result = []
  result = [[items0.split('|'), items1.split('|'), items2.split('|')].flat()]
  const obj = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  let prov = []
  items0.split('|').forEach(item0 => prov.push(obj.race[item0]))
  result.push(prov)
  obj.race.registers.forEach(o => {
    let prov = []
    items0.split('|').forEach(item0 => prov.push(''))
    items1.split('|').forEach(item1 => prov.push(o[item1]))
    var pegaAttributes = JSON.parse(o.pegaAttributes)
    items2.split('|').forEach(item2 => prov.push(pegaAttributes[item2]))
    result.push(prov)
  })
  return result
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but how did you call for the function in the cell? I'm getting ```Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues (line 13).```

Comment: I tried calling the function using a button > assign script with "getDataMyJSON" and it got the data. I'm just wondering how I can do this inside a cell.

Comment: You can't call it as a function the way it's setup. You would need to return a value in an array.

Comment: @pgSystemTester I'm trying to understand what "return a value in an array" means. But it's difficult since I'm giving my first steps in programming. I'm wondering if I can make this script to do something like this: ```=getDataMyJSON("https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/game-api/race/details/69357391", "/raceTime", "/topSpeed", "/lastSpeed")``` so then I'd call the function this way inside a cell allowing me to call for each attribute according to my needs. Similar to how IMPORTJSON is used. I'll have a look at this later and see if I can do it. Maybe I'll have a look at how IMPORTJSON works.

Comment: i'll add as an answer. You're doing fine.

Comment: @Verminous at the bottom of mine is an example of how it could be done. I wasn't sure how you wanted the data, but hopefully between multiple answers you've got a path forward.

Comment: I have edited my nswer, take the second part after edit. Do not hesitate to tell me if something is not clear!

Comment: @MikeSteelson It is clear thank you!  I was trying to add an ```ìtem0``` so I could also import the values within ```race```like ```totalReward```, ```length``` etc. Is this doable inside the same function or would it have to be a seperate one?
I tried to add this ```function importDataJSON2(url, items0, items1, items2)``` then this below ```result = [[items0.split('|'),items1.split('|'),items2.split('|')].flat()]``` also ```items0.split('|').forEach(item0 => prov.push(o[item0]))
    var pegaAttributes = JSON.parse(o.pegaAttributes)``` but get error ```obj.race.forEach is not a function```.

Comment: take the new edition - note that there is only one occurrence of items0 and several occurrences of items1 & items2 - be careful not to get a 403 error due to too many queries - you can also do a traditional query for items0 as you did before

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse it twice as that's an object just as text. I think using the custom formula might not be easiest since Google App Scripts can do this for you pretty cleanly. Consider using the standard `JSON.parse()` functions.

The below function got me the following values you were looking for. See the debug screen shot.

```
function getJSONData(){
  const zURL = 'https://api-apollo.pegaxy.io/v1/game-api/race/details/69357391';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(zURL);
  var cleanedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
  var theRace = cleanedResponse['race'];
  var theRegisters = theRace['registers'];
  var aRegister = theRegisters[0];
  var oneID = oneRegister.id;
  var aGate = oneRegister.gate;
  var aPega = oneRegister.pegaAttributes;
  var cleanedPega = JSON.parse(aPega);
  var zTopSpeed = cleanedPega.topSpeed;

}
```

If you debug this, function and check to the right in your variables, you should be able to get everything you need. You'll have to find a way to get it back into sheets, but the values are available.

[image]

[image]

## Updated

A request was made to figure out how this could be run as a Sheets Function. leveraging Mike Steelson's approach and presumption for what is needed as far as races... here's a function that could be used. Just paste the URL in the formula.

```
function getDataMyJSON(theURL) {

  const data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(theURL).getContentText())
  const items = ['raceTime','topSpeed','lastSpeed']
  let result=[]
  data.race.registers.forEach(x => {
    let prov = []
    prov.push(x.raceId)
    var p = JSON.parse(x.pegaAttributes)
    items.forEach(i => prov.push(p[i]))
    result.push(prov)
  })
  return result;
}
```

So then put the URL in the formula and you'd get this...

[image]

Comment: Hey @pgSystemTester thank you for your reply and comments. I´ll go with Mike's reply as it allows me to choose the attributes I need to import from within the cell without me needing to change the function code.

Comment: @Verminous thanks for the explanation and I totally get  it -- my answer was a bit lazy and his was pretty slick. I appreciate the upvote and the interesting question (plus I am curious about this racing game....)

Comment: Ah yes I see you are into Crypto and Ethereum. Check it out its interesting and still a good time to get on board (meaning cheap).